# jquery converting json string to array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting Json string from my server as below

```
var str = {"12:30 PM":"1:00 PM","11:30 AM":"12:00 PM"}
```

I want to convert it in an array like

```
var str = [["12:30 PM","1:00 PM"], ["11:30 AM","12:00 PM"]];
```

How would I do that?

I tried to convert using `jQuery.parseJSON(str)`, but it's giving error.

I also researched a lot in stackoverflow and there seems to be many solutionfor this problem but none of the solution is working for this issue.

Comment: Try `var str = '{"12:30 PM":"1:00 PM","11:30 AM":"12:00 PM"}';`

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611845/how-to-convert-a-json-formatted-string-into-a-json-array-in-javascript

Comment: Never say *"but it's giving error"* without actually posting the error message.

Answer (score 2):

The `str` is already an object.

You could use [jQuery.map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) method.

```
var str = {"12:30 PM":"1:00 PM","11:30 AM":"12:00 PM"};
var result = $.map(str, function(value, key) {
  return [[key, value]];
});
```

Comment: Didn't even notice the [tag:jquery] tag :). Nice answer and doesn't require pollyfills for IE8 support (unless it's jQuery 2.x)

Answer (score 1):

Try this `map` example

```
var str = {"12:30 PM":"1:00 PM","11:30 AM":"12:00 PM"};
var convert = Object.keys(str).map(function(k) {
    return [k, str[k]];
});
```

If you need support for IE <= 8, see [Object.keys pollyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Polyfill) and [Array.prototype.map pollyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill)

Comment: thanks for the response. I get error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object"

Comment: @user2584596 That shouldn't happen given the value of `str` in your question

Comment: I am using Chrome Version 31.0.1650.63 m, pretty latest.

Comment: I am using a jQuery plugin called Jquery.timepicker. here is the URL http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/ . This plugin require data in the format as I mentioned in my question. Your method works when I hardcode str =  {"12:30 PM":"1:00 PM","11:30 AM":"12:00 PM"}; and then convert. However I am getting same data via Ajax call, so it's data coming from the Ajax which is not working. I copied data in str from console.log(data from ajax) so I am pretty sure it's same data

Comment: @user2584596 Then you need to show more code in your question as well as any error messages you see

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = '{"12:30 PM":"1:00 PM","11:30 AM":"12:00 PM"}';
object = JSON.parse(str);
var my_array = new Array();

for(var key in object ){
    my_array[key] = object[key];
}
```

Comment: It's not working.. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.

```
var p = {"12:30 PM":"1:00 PM","11:30 AM":"12:00 PM"} 
var o = [];

for (k in p) {
    if (p.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        o.push([k, p[k]]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Gotta be careful with `for..in` loops. In some circumstances they can pick up more properties than you might expect

Comment: @Phil Can you please mention any instance?

Comment: Here's some more reading - http://jslinterrors.com/the-body-of-a-for-in-should-be-wrapped-in-an-if-statement/

Comment: @Phil Does hasOwnProperty chekcing make any effect?

Comment: Yes, that's the recommended method of checking

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're talking about actual *string* that you're getting from the server, you can do a plain string replacement:

```
var str = '{"12:30 PM":"1:00 PM","11:30 AM":"12:00 PM"}';

str = str
.replace('{"','[["')
.replace('"}','"]]')
.replace('","','"],["')
.replace(/":"/g,'","')
```

This will make `str` into *string* representing an array. To make a real array out of it you can do something like this:

```
var arr;
eval('arr = ' + str);
```

This is the only legitimate use of `eval` I can advocate.

**Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/h8c6w/**

Comment: Instead of `eval`, you could use `JSON.parse(str)` and then map the object to a new array (see other answers)

Comment: thanks for your answer, unfortunately it gives error : Uncaught TypeError: Object [["12:30 PM","1:00 PM"],["11:30 AM","12:00 PM"]] has no method 'sort'

Comment: Would the downvoter please explain horrible vices of this answer? Perhaps by modifying working jsfiddle demo?

Comment: @user2584596 do not call `str.sort();` in the example above - `str` is still a string. Instead call `arr.sort();` - `arr` being a real array